# Jekyll avatar image size adjustment in yml config file

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I have installed a Jekyll based website which has a config file _config.yml. The file contains following section where avatar image is path is specified.

```
author:
  name   : "name of the author"
  avatar : "/assets/images/avatar_logo.jpg"
```

I want to adjust the size of the avatar image on the final rendered web's home page. Most of the search I did was related to the markup pages but this is a the main config file which is in yml.

Not sure how to change/adjust the image size here.

Comment: Are you using a plugin to display that avatar? What accesses this config setting? It's not a Jekyll built-in, as far as I know.